# R: how to replace NAs with a median by rows?

Tags: r, median

It is a very simple task to replace NAs with medians by column. But how to replace NA values with a row median? I tried `matrixStats::rowMedians` and it does not work.

Sample:

```
 tibble(
   name = LETTERS[1:5],
   name2 = LETTERS[9:13],
   id = 1:5,
   val1 = rnorm(5, 0.05, 0.5),
   val2 = rnorm(5, 0, 1),
   val3 = c(1, 2, NA, 7, 0.55),
   val4 = c(NA, 2.33, 12, -0.444, 0)
  )


# A tibble: 5 x 7
  name  name2    id    val1   val2  val3   val4
  <chr> <chr> <int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     I         1  0.160  -1.62   1    NA    
2 B     J         2  0.194   0.345  2     2.33 
3 C     K         3  0.681   1.18  NA    12    
4 D     L         4  0.0168 -0.385  7    -0.444
5 E     M         5 -0.509  -1.10   0.55  0
```

I tried this code and it gives me an error:

```
sample <- sample %>%
       mutate_all(~ifelse(is.na(.), matrixStats::rowMedians(., na.rm = T), .))

Problem with `mutate()` input `val3`.
x Argument 'dim.' must be an integer vector of length two.
i Input `val3` is `(structure(function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) ...`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I understand that `matrixStats::rowMedians` wants me to transform my data to a matrix. But when I transform my data to the matrix, I cannot perform `mutate` function. When I try to implement `rowMedians` straight away, I recieve errors:

```
sample <- matrixStats::rowMedians(sample, cols = c("val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"))
Error in matrixStats::rowMedians(sample, cols = c("val1", "val2", "val3",  :
  Argument 'x' must be of type logical, integer or numeric, not 'character'.
```

`as.matrix` converts my data from the `numeric` to `character`. However, on my original dataset I receive another error:

```
Error in matrixStats::rowMedians(original_df, cols = c(val1, val2, val3,  :
  object 'val1' was not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(across(val1:val4, 
               ~ if_else(is.na(.), pmap_dbl(across(val1:val4), ~ median(c(...), na.rm = TRUE)), .)))
                    
  name  name2    id   val1   val2  val3   val4
  <chr> <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     I         1 -0.660  1.68   1     1    
2 B     J         2  0.145  1.04   2     2.33 
3 C     K         3 -1.26   2.54   2.54 12    
4 D     L         4 -0.788 -0.562  7    -0.444
5 E     M         5  0.821  1.74   0.55  0
```

Comment: It seems that your code is working, thank you. But performing it on my original dataframe gives me incorrect median values.

Comment: Seems like the median is calculated column wise and not row wise. For example, ```c(7, 7, 7, NA)``` gives me ```8``` instead of ```7```.

Comment: I see, you are right, it wasn't the correct solution. I reworked it accordingly.

Comment: @tmfmmk yes, now it works as it should work. Tjank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stay in `tidyverse` one way would be to reshape the data :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('val'), 
               names_to = 'col') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value = replace(value, is.na(value), median(value, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) %>%
  ungroup
```

In base R, we can use `apply` :

```
cols <- grep('val', names(df))
df[cols] <- t(apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) 
              replace(x, is.na(x), median(x, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Comment: The base R solution is very good. I find it better than the way I impute row medians in one of my personal functions. Do you find this solution sufficiently reliable to use inside a function or are there some use cases in which it will give an unexpected result?

Comment: This should be reliable just take care to include all the variables you want to include in `cols`.